# Flask App, Gunicorn not seeing a custom class?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I have a flask application that runs fine in my Jupyter notebook and as app.py on my local machine.  However, when I deploy to a cloud (Render), I am getting a Gunicorn error saying that it can't get an attribute (a custom class that I need)

I have to define some custom classes:

```
class SegLabelListCustom(SegmentationLabelList):
def open(self, fn): return open_mask(fn, div=True)

class SegItemListCustom(SegmentationItemList):
_label_cls = SegLabelListCustom
```

Prior to opening a saved deep learning file:

```
learn = load_learner(path, 'cell_export.pkl')
```

This works fine in my Jupyter notebook and running locally app.py serve

However, when I deploy in cloud (which uses Gunicorn), I get the following error:

```
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/gunicorn", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.setup(app)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 120, in setup
    self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/app.py", line 49, in <module>
    learn = load_learner(path, export_file_name)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/basic_train.py", line 598, in load_learner
    state = torch.load(source, map_location='cpu') if defaults.device == torch.device('cpu') else torch.load(source)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 387, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 574, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SegItemListCustom' on <module '__main__' from '/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/gunicorn'>
```

I am not sure how to address or troubleshoot this.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I too am facing a similar issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It is due to the pickling in case anyone wants to know.